# Add share option to chat web-app with socket.io or others

Tags: socket.io

I made a chat webapp with socket.io, and we can just share text, and i want to add a file share option, how can i do it?
(Please answer with an example)

I know with socket.io, we can upload file in server, but how can we download it?